# Pass an additional parameter into a function whose first argument is a function pointer

Tags: c++, function, oop, pointers

Suppose we have have the class `VirtualGridDriver` with public member function:

```
static CString AddTask(void (*proc)(VGridTaskParam parameters, CString str),
                       VGridTaskParam parameters, CString str);
```

Moreover, suppose we have the class `CSchedulerDlg` with public member function:

```
static void runJob(VGridTaskParam parameters, CString str);
```

Note that the class `VGridTaskParam`contains **some** necessary paramaters to add a task to a queue.

In my `main()` source code, I can write, and successful run the function call:

```
VirtualGridDriver::AddTask(&CSchedulerDlg::runJob, parameters, m_strConnection);
```

I am simply interested in passing an additional parameter into `VirtualGridDriver::AddTask` as follows:

```
VirtualGridDriver::AddTask(&CSchedulerDlg::runJob, parameters, m_strConnection, x);
```

where x is an `int`.

Please notice the additional integer (**which would be instantiated in main() scope**) is passed into the above function. I am not interested in changing the `VGridTaskParam` class.

**Please comment if anything is unclear. I will quickly add additional information.**

---

**Update**: I have done as the comments suggested, but I now I get an error. 
This is what I changed:

In `VirtualGridDriver`, I now have:

```
static CString AddTask(void (*proc)(VGridTaskParam parameters, CString str, int x), VGridTaskParam parameters, CString str, int x);
```

In `CSchedulerDlg`, I now have:

```
static void runJob(VGridTaskParam parameters, CString strConnection, int x);
```

The error I get from these changes is:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_ofstream > CSchedulerDlg::impFl" (?impFl@CSchedulerDlg@@2V?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@A)

Usually this error is because the function definition is not found in the .cpp file, but I have it as follows:

```
void CSchedulerDlg::runJob(VGridTaskParam parameters, CString strConnection, int x) {// do stuff}
```

With these changes, I should be able to invoke the method as:

```
int x = 1;
VirtualGridDriver::AddTask(&CSchedulerDlg::runJob, parameters, m_strConnection, x);
```

However, I still receive the aforementioned error message.

Comment: just add the parameter to the `AddTask` method, or provide an overload to it. I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: You need to overload the function AddTask in VirtualGridDriver class

Comment: @bolov I have tried to do this but I get the error:  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > CSchedulerDlg::impFl". Any ideas?

Comment: @Pii without seeing the code that generated error, no

Comment: @bolov I have added the relevant code to my question. If I didn't include enough code please let me know and I will add as necessary. thank you

Comment: need a definition for `AddTask` with the extra `int`, like you have done for `runJob`